# argrapser nargs='?' returns None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an option in code:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--deploy', nargs='?', default='develop', help=('Deploy Unity project to appropriate URL, need to be enclosed with config_name'))
```

Which must return `default='develop'` value, afaik, if nothing passed.

Instead -  I have `None`:

```
 Namespace(buildtype='dev', confgen=None, configlist=False, deploy=None, refresh=False, tagcheck=False, uuidgen=None)
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Python 2.7